# Is it possible to restrict access to Reporting Services over HTTP by ip address?

Tags: url, reporting-services, ip-address, access-control

I'm trying to deploy my Reporting Services application to a remote site. I'm using url access and I want to impersonate a user based on an ip address range.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by putting some firewall rules between the reports server and the client you could stop deny/allow certain ip addresses, but i've never come across anything like that built into reporting services

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything like that built into Reporting Services.  But I can think of a couple of alternatives.

1. Usually the Reporting Services website and web service are running under IIS.  You can configure IIS to block access by IP address.  Depending on what version of IIS you are using, the instruction may vary.  I would just google it.  This would be the easiest way in my opinion.
2. First thing to note is that I haven't tested the second way, it is just an idea.  Since the Reporting Services website and web service run under Asp.Net, in theory you could create a custom IHttpModule and add it to the web.config.  Hanselman has an nice article about coding up such a IHttpModule and configuring the web.config [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnIPAddressBlockingHttpModuleForASPNETIn9Minutes.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but we are trying to do the same thing.  Firewall is the way to do it - SSRS doesn't use IIS, so it isn't possible through IIS.